# Print two rows in one column [Advanced SQL]

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

Good day guys,

I am stuck here and I desperately need help here...

Apparently, I am trying to combine two rows into one column.

My current sql dan table design is:

```
select * from timetable order by name, id
```

which gives me this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG26E.png)

Does anyone know how to design my query, so that I will get a result like this:

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rCOv.png)

Fyi, I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2005.

Thanks in advance guys ! :)

Sorry that I could not upload the image here.

SORRY... I posted the same image !! Sorry !!

I have uploaded the new one.. Please have a look..

Comment: I'm not able to see a single change in the images you have posted

Comment: Can you check the links? I think is the same image

Comment: Your questions links two times to the same picture.

Comment: You linked to the same image twice.

Comment: For me both images with query result look the same. Also links to them look the same.

Comment: Good to know everyone agrees :) I was having doubts about whether they were the same or not

Comment: @MostyMostacho you can see that it's the same link ;)

Comment: I am so sorry guys.. My bad.. I posted the same image..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COALESCE(i.Name, o.Name) [Name],
        i.Time [TimeIN],
        MIN(o.Time) [TimeOUT]
FROM    (   SELECT  *
            FROM    Timetable
            WHERE   Status = 'IN'
        ) i
        FULL OUTER JOIN 
        (   SELECT  *
            FROM    Timetable
            WHERE   Status = 'OUT'
        ) o
            ON o.Name = i.Name
            AND o.Time > i.Time
GROUP BY COALESCE(i.Name, o.Name), i.Time 
ORDER BY Name, TimeIN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot GarethD. Let me try it tomorrow morning in the office !!! Thanks a lot !! =)

Comment: @KikiChandra - If this has helped please mark it as the answer to remove it from the "Unanswered" Questions. Thanks